# Are there pitfalls to this solution to read messages from a queue in parallel?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, queue, task-parallel-library

I've posted a question on stackoverflow: [How can I consequently read messages from a queue in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437298/how-can-i-consequently-read-messages-from-a-queue-in-parallel/34589208#34589208) I would like my own answer to be reviewed.

## Situation

We have one message queue. We would like to process messages in parallel and limit the number of simultaneously processed messages.

## Our solution

Based on answers given and some research of our own, we've come to a solution. We're using a `SemaphoreSlim` to limit our number of parallel Tasks.

**Are there any pitfalls to this solution?**
I'm also interested in any better solutions.

```
static string queue = @".\Private$\concurrenttest";

private static async Task Process(CancellationToken token)
{
    MessageQueue msMq = new MessageQueue(queue);
    msMq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Command1) });
    SemaphoreSlim s = new SemaphoreSlim(15, 15);

    while (true)
    {
        await s.WaitAsync();
        await PeekAsync(msMq);
        Command1 message = await ReceiveAsync(msMq);
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await HandleMessage(message);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Exception handling
            }
            s.Release();
        });
    }
}

private static Task HandleMessage(Command1 message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + message.id + ", name: " + message.name);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return Task.FromResult(1);
}

private static Task<Message> PeekAsync(MessageQueue msMq)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync<Message>(msMq.BeginPeek(), msMq.EndPeek);
}

public class Command1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

private static async Task<Command1> ReceiveAsync(MessageQueue msMq)
{
    var receiveAsync = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Message>(msMq.BeginReceive(), msMq.EndPeek);
    return (Command1)receiveAsync.Body;
}
```

Comment: `Command1` is just a testbody for the messages that are send through the MessageQueue. [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) is a Class from .NET Framework. It should limit the number of threads that access the code block, in this case 15.

Comment: Do you dequeue the messages or is it not necessary? I feel like you are not dequeueing them and that can lead to problems

Comment: `ReceiveAsync()` dequeues a message from the queue. `PeekAsync()` check if there are any messages.

Comment: "consequently"? Do you mean concurrently? Or "consecutively" (which implies some sort of ordering, so hopefully not that)?

Comment: That might be a faulty translation. I meant to say that it should keep reading as long as the application is running (and there are messages available).

Comment: I can imagine some scenarios where you'll have problems if this code is running in multiple processes (same or different systems). The multiple processes will be in a race condition between the peek and dequeue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Readability**

Use keyword `var` any time that the initialization of the variable clearly tells what the variable represents. Avoid abbreviations in variable names.

```
var messageQueue = new MessageQueue(queue);
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(15, 15);
```

---

**Configuration**

Avoid hard-coded settings:

> ```
> var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(15, 15);
> ```

Make use of a pattern to allow the number of concurrent processing jobs to be configurable (instance property, configuration file, ..).

---

**Main Loop**

The main loop `while (true)` is considered a code smell by some because it's not clear what the exit conditions are. But what's definately an issue is that the loop never exits. Always make sure the loop has a graceful exit. Since there's a cancellation token provided, why not use it to drive the loop?

*sand-box mode:*

```
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // .. loop body
}
```

*explicit mode:*

```
while (true)
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    // .. loop body
}
```

---

**Threading Integrity**

Once you have acquired the semaphore, you should immediately use the try-finally block to make sure to always release it.

> ```
> await semaphore.WaitAsync();
>
> // What if the code below throws an exception? The semaphore is not released!
> await PeekAsync(messageQueue);
> var message = await ReceiveAsync(messageQueue);
> ```

```
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
try
{
    // .. code while holding lock
}
finally 
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

---

**MessageQueue**

There is no reason to peek before receiving, because [both operations are blocking on the same trigger - an incoming message](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue?view=netframework-4.8).

> ```
> await PeekAsync(messageQueue);
> var message = await ReceiveAsync(messageQueue);
> ```

You can replace the above with:

```
var message = await ReceiveAsync(messageQueue);
```